# How do I obtain the Versionone's "Done" hours through its RESTful API?

Tags: versionone

For example: When I look for all the attributes of a Task
 
`https://<host>/VersionOne/rest-1.v1/Data/Task`
I get information like "Todo" and "DetailedEstimates" but nothing related to the "Done" hrs

Do you know if there is a way to get the "Done" hrs for a given task/Test/etc through the Rest API of VersionOne?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Done" is not a single value and thus must be queried for through the relation. The asset type that represents one entry of hours is called an Actual. The relation, through the Workitem base is called Actuals.

So you would 'root' your query with something like Story, or even Workitem. Then use the 'sel' to select the member and value (hours).

```
http://<host>/VersionOne/rest-1.v1/Data/Story?sel=Name,Actuals.Date,Actuals.Value,Actuals.Member
```

That might be a bit overwhelming data-wise, so you'll probably want to limit it to one story:

```
/rest-1.v1/Data/Story/1038?sel=Name,Actuals.Date,Actuals.Value,Actuals.Member
```

Please note that if you track at the task/test level and not the story level you'll have to navigate that relation as well:

```
/rest-1.v1/Data/Story/1031?sel=Name,Actuals.Date,Actuals.Value,Actuals.Member,Children.Actuals.Date,Children.Actuals.Value,Children.Actuals.Member
```

The other way you could do it is from the Actual asset itself. The data would be the same but the result might be more consumable:

```
/rest-1.v1/Data/Actual?sel=Date,Value,Member.Name,Workitem.Name
```

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, you can have all the Actual Values summed up for each Task

```
https://<host>/VersionOne/rest-1.v1/Data/Task?sel=Name,Actuals.Value.@Sum
```

Comment: This really helped as well but I don't have enough "reputation points" to mark this one